# Is there a better way of changing transparency of gnome terminal window? I don't like using the mouse

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal

I find myself needing to adjust the transparency of my terminal window quite often. I go to preferences > profiles > edit to change the level of transparency, but what I'd really like is a quick command or alias that I can enter from the terminal. Does something like this exist? If not, can someone point me in a direction of how I can create it myself. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `dconf watch /` in the terminal and then change the transparency value using the mouse. You'll see output like so:

```
$ dconf watch /
/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/background-transparency-percent
  51

/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/background-transparency-percent
  51

/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/background-transparency-percent
  52
```

Note the dconf key path: `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/background-transparency-percent` (it might be different for you). You can use that with `dconf write` to set the transparency:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/background-transparency-percent 60
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/background-transparency-percent 10
```

Comment: You're welcome! If this worked, considering accepting it: https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers :)

Comment: This approach sets the transparency of all gnome-terminal windows and tabs (of this profile) at once. If that's what you're looking for then it's perfect. If you want to change transparency individually for windows/tabs, you should define multiple profiles for several transparency values, and toggle using the right-click menu (also easily accessible via the keyboard if it has a "right-click" key).

Answer (score 0):

for tmux

```sh
bind t command-prompt -p "Enter Opacity %" "run \"xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d ' ' -f 5) -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY $(printf 0x%x $((0xffffffff * %% / 100)))\""
```